# iFrame with new https opening up in a new window without the FB chrome around it and form submission opening up in a new window

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, https

Got a bit of a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I've had an application out on FB for about a year now, but when I switched to https, now the pages open up in a new tab on the browser, and form submits are opening up in new windows.  This is a facebook app written in PHP.

Here's what I've done so far:

FB 
   - Created a new app
   - Set the secure url to the https:// site.
   - Set all of the new options settings to enable all the right things.

My Server 
   - Set up the certificate
   - Set up the app under the httpsdoc directory

My Code 
   - Pointed all URL links to the https://myserver directory from the http://apps.facebook.com/myapp links
   - Changed all of the form submits to submit to the secure location.

What am I missing?